# m4a/mp3 files to wav for Bing Speech API

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, speech-recognition, botframework, azure-cognitive-services

Bing Speech API only accepts wav files so I have been trying to convert m4a (Skype) and mp3 (Facebook) audio files I am getting in my chatbot to wav format. I am using fluent-ffmpeg in node.js.

For now, I am downloading the audio file, converting it to wav and returning the piped output for use ahead.

```
if (attachment.contentType === 'audio/x-m4a') {
  request.get(attachment.contentUrl).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('file.m4a'));
  var command = ffmpeg('file.m4a')
        .toFormat('wav')
        .on('error', function (err) {
            console.log('An error occurred: ' + err.message);
        })
        .on('progress', function (progress) {
            // console.log(JSON.stringify(progress));
            console.log('Processing: ' + progress.targetSize + ' KB converted');
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('Processing finished !');
        });

  return command.pipe();
}
```

Right now, the conversion works when I send the m4a file through the botframework-emulator on my pc. But when I specify my pc as the endpoint (through ngrok) and try to send the m4a file from the chat test at the bot framework [developer end](https://dev.botframework.com/), ffmpeg returns an error:

```
An error occurred: ffmpeg exited with code 1: file.m4a: Invalid data found when processing input
```

But when I play the downloaded m4a file, it plays alright.

The content URL is https in the second case if that matters.

Kindly help me with two things:

1. Downloading, Converting and Returning without storing anything on my end
2. Downloading/Accessing m4a/mp3 files properly

I am new to streams, pipes and ffmpeg and all the above code is after googling.

Comment: Try [audio-buffer-to-wave](https://www.npmjs.com/package/audiobuffer-to-wav) NPM module. Example: https://github.com/Jam3/audiobuffer-to-wav/blob/master/demo/index.js

Comment: can you help me on I'm trying to download the attachment but its store in 0B. var attachment = session.message.attachments[0];
                request.get(attachment.contentUrl).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(attachment.name));